# Why "read" method doesn't appear when I use "dir" built-in function on a "os.popen()" object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I call the next object:

```
>>> import os
>>> data = os.popen("ipconfig") #this right here
```

I tried to find "read" method using "dir" built-in function:

```
>>> dir(data)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__e
q__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__
gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt_
_', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__'
, '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_p
roc', '_stream', 'close']
```

And when I use "read" directly it works ok:

```
>>> data2 = data.read()
>>>
```

Is there any way to find all those "hidden" methods?.

Comment: Because it works perfect for strings, integers, floating point, complex, lists, tuple, etc. objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `data` is `_wrap_close`, which forwards attribute lookups through its `__getattr__`. You'll find your `read` method in `dir(data._stream)`.